# Games fail to launch return code: 13568 - App not starting

Tags: 20.04, wine, games, winetricks, lutris

```
Initial process has exited (return code: 13568)
Monitored process exited.
Exit with return code 13568
```

I've tried multiple clean prefixes.

Comment: Check with `https://www.winehq.org`. Not all Windows programs are available through `wine`. This is not a Ubuntu problem, this is a `wine` problem.